# Any way that I can hide a value from the list from select dropdown based on the value in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know how can I hide the value from the dropdown list with jQuery?

Example:

If I have a dropdown as following:

```
<select name="Test" id="Test">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Test1</option>
    <option value="2">Test2</option>
    <option value="3">Test3</option>
    <option value="4">Test4</option>
    <option value="5">Test5</option>
    <option value="6">Test6</option>
</select>
```

How can I hide the list value if the value is 2, 3, 4 in jQuery? So the output will be as below

```
<select name="Test" id="Test">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Test1</option>
    <option value="5">Test5</option>
    <option value="6">Test6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Did you need to remove or just hide the option elements?

Comment: @Alex: just hide the option elements

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't want to get rid of them, the best you can do is disable them. I would guess that based on the same value that could hide them, changing that same value could potentially cause them to reappear. If that's the case you'd disable/enable them.

```
$('#Test').find('options[value=2], options[value=3]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

If you wanna remove them...

```
$('#Test').find('options[value=2], options[value=3').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can hide those elements but you can remove them:

```
$('#Test').find('option[value=2], option[value=3], option[value=4]').remove();
```

Comment: what about `$('#Test').find('options[value=2], options[value=3],options[value=4]').hide();`

Comment: @diEcho: That doesn't do anything (in WebKit or Opera, works in Firefox4, didn't bother checking IE), not even after fixing the "options -> option" typo. http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/7dWVL/

Comment: @diEcho `.hide()` I also try this but its not working with older browser, specially IE8 and below. If older browser can implement this, this could be the closest answer.

Comment: It would be nice if `<option>` elements paid attention to `display:none` but they don't in Chrome, Safari, and Opera even though they do in Firefox, I still don't know about IE, I haven't cranked up my browser testing labs (i.e. pulled the Windows machines out of my closet). I don't know what the standards say about `display:none` on `<option>` so I can't say who is right, not that "right" matters that much when confronting reality of course.

Answer (score 1):

```
function filter_select( dom, filter ){
  var cache = $(dom).children('option').clone();
  $(dom).children('option').each( function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    ( filter.indexOf( Number( $this.val() ) ) > -1 ) && $this.remove();
  });
  return function undo(){
    console.log('reattaching original options');
    $(dom).empty().append(cache);
  };
}
```

usage :

```
$(function(){
  var u = filter_select('#Test', [2,3,4]);
  // now you can call u() to undo the filter, if you want.
})
```